# How to get more space on /dev/mapper/centos-root

Tags: centos, linux-disk-free

The following is `df -h` result. `/dev/mapper/centos-root` is 100%.

```
/dev/mapper/centos-root    50G   50G   20K  100% /
devtmpfs                  3.8G     0  3.8G    0% /dev
tmpfs                     3.9G  8.0K  3.9G    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     3.9G  8.9M  3.8G    1% /run
tmpfs                     3.9G     0  3.9G    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-home   406G  5.0G  401G    2% /home
/dev/sda3                 497M  303M  195M   61% /boot
tmpfs                     780M     0  780M    0% /run/user/0
tmpfs                     780M     0  780M    0% /run/user/1000
```

I removed a lot of large files (nGB) in $HOME and $HOME/Downloads. But there is no change in `df -h` result.

Could you tell me where I should remove files to get more space on `/dev/mapper/centos-root`?

Comment: Please note this question belongs on ServerFault, rather that SO which is for programming questions

Answer (score 1):

Your Home directory is mounted from partition

```
/dev/mapper/centos-home
```

Try deleting unimportant files for example in

```
/tmp/
```

If you want to examine the file sizes have a look at the `du` command

Answer (score -1):

The following is `df -i result. /dev/mapper/vg00-lv_var 6553600 6553600 0  100% /var`

```
Filesystem                 Inodes   IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_root 49856512  220435 49636077    1% /
devtmpfs                 16444850     583 16444267    1% /dev
tmpfs                    16448811       6 16448805    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    16448811     986 16447825    1% /run
tmpfs                    16448811      16 16448795    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                   32768      35    32733    1% /boot
/dev/sda1                       0       0        0     - /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_var   6553600 6553600        0  100% /var
tmpfs                    16448811      17 16448794    1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                    16448811       1 16448810    1% /run/user/0
tmpfs                    16448811       1 16448810    1% /run/user/99
```